# In 'Better Call Saul'

Tags: idioms-in-context

In 'Better Call Saul', an assistant says to her boss: "there is a lot of prep we pushed so that you could focus on getting someone up". Does that mean she put off prep or managed to make  preparations?

Comment: Pushed through, completed as a priority.

Comment: reza, please take more care with your typing.